# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" - But it is

Tags: c#

So this seems like a problem that comes up a reasonable amount (Based on questions with the same title), but i'm stumped by my occurrence.
I have inherited code, and I'm really confused by an error I'm getting

I have an object

```
FiscalSamplingPoint currentPoint
```

pretty basic definition

```
public sealed class FiscalSamplingPoint : SamplingPoint, IComparable<FiscalSamplingPoint>, IEquatable<FiscalSamplingPoint>
{
    private readonly int _fiscalYear;
    private readonly int _periodNumber;
    private readonly FiscalPeriodType _periodType;

...
}
```

FiscalPeriodType is an enum

I have a SortedList (unsure why they are using it as a dictionary) "absolutes" of key FiscalSamplingPoint.

```
SortedList<FiscalSamplingPoint, PeriodsRepositoryRange>
```

on a specific currentPoint it throws the given key not present exception, and as excepted,

```
absolutes.containsKey(currentPoint)
```

is false (visual studio 2010 watch debugger)

However, we have overriden GetHashCode and Equals.

and again using visual studio's watch debugger I do

```
currentPoint.GetHashCode
```

and

```
(new System.Collections.Generic.System_DictionaryDebugView<TR.API.Common.FiscalSamplingPoint,TR.API.Common.PeriodsRepositoryRange>(absolutes)).Items[3].Key.GetHashCode()
```

and both return the same result (62234 to be exact)

and

```
currentPoint.Equals((new System.Collections.Generic.System_DictionaryDebugView<TR.API.Common.FiscalSamplingPoint,TR.API.Common.PeriodsRepositoryRange>(absolutes)).Items[3].Key)
```

returns true.

I really have no clue at this point what could be the issue.  any pointers would be appreciated.

edit: here are relevant functions

```
public bool Equals(FiscalSamplingPoint obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    return InternalEquals(obj);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != typeof (FiscalSamplingPoint)) return false;
        return InternalEquals((FiscalSamplingPoint) obj);
}

private bool InternalEquals(FiscalSamplingPoint obj)
{
    return _fiscalYear == obj.FiscalYear && _periodNumber == obj.PeriodNumber && _periodType == obj.PeriodType;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return 31*_fiscalYear + 53*_periodNumber + 13*(int) _periodType;
}
```

For IComparable we have a few functions that work together

```
    public int CompareTo(FiscalSamplingPoint other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Other object is null");
        }

        if (this > other)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (Equals(other))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static bool operator <(FiscalSamplingPoint point1, FiscalSamplingPoint point2)
    {
        if (point1._periodType < point2._periodType)
            return true;

        if (point1._fiscalYear < point2._fiscalYear)
            return true;

        if (point1._fiscalYear == point2._fiscalYear)
            return point1.PeriodNumber < point2.PeriodNumber;

        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator >(FiscalSamplingPoint point1, FiscalSamplingPoint point2)
    {
        if (point1._periodType > point2._periodType)
            return true;

        if (point1._fiscalYear > point2._fiscalYear)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (point1._fiscalYear == point2._fiscalYear)
        {
            return point1.PeriodNumber > point2.PeriodNumber;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I can't quite tell where the code begins and where the dialog ends

Comment: If you could post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), than that would help a lot

Comment: Must show how did you override equal. This is the primary suspect here.

Comment: Standard mistake is to allow the key object to mutate.  In other words, have a different hash code before and after it was put in the dictionary.  So it is in the wrong bucket.

Comment: filling in the story, with the relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I think you should investigate Hans Passant's idea. ReSharper also gives this warning when GetHashCode uses mutable values. Try setting all fields used to calculate GetHashCode to readonly to make sure they are not changed.

Comment: change that, they are already read-only, adding more to the code.

Comment: The GetHashCode and Equals implementations look dodgy

Comment: Show your implementations of `IComparable` and `IEquatable` interfaces.

Comment: I didn't write them, so have nothing invested in them, but going to add the other interface methods in a moment - should be there now.

Comment: During the dictionary creation the key of the sorted list is set to the reference to 'FiscalSamplingPoint' and not using that point's hashcode as the key. If you were, you would know because `.Items[3].Key` would be equal to `currentPoint.GetHashCode()`

Comment: @AzZa, having a hard time parsing what you wrote.  I know it should be the reference, hence why I'm also confused by absolutes.containsKey(currentPoint) being false.

With that said, have to run soon and will probably start attacking this again in the morning.  Have a clue on what the problem could be.

Comment: Please also add the implementation of the `PeriodNumber` property inside `FiscalSamplingPoint`. I'm thinking that the comparers are not correct. SordedList<T,K> under the covers, uses `Array.BinarySearch<TKey>(this.keys, 0, this._size, key, this.comparer)` to see if key is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of `<` and `>` operators is the reason that the `absolutes.containsKey(currentPoint)` returns `false` even when the key is present in the list. `SordedList<T,K>` uses BinarySearch to look for the key in the list, but can't find it because the list is not sorted properly.

Most likely the Enum values play a major role to incorrect comparison. Their numerical value is greater than, even thought the contextual meaning might be less.

I suspect the you can change the `<` and `>` operators to something like what Will is suggesting in his answer.

Comment: You're right that the implementations of < and > are faulty, but yours is incorrect too.  It will incorrectly return false when type and year match, but period is <.

Comment: Will you are correct, sir. It seemed logical at the time I wrote it. Your solution is definitely cleaner.

Comment: No probs, hopefully the OP has got what he needed from our combined efforts.

Comment: was sick on friday so wasn't able to followup, but this was my thinking as well.  turns out, the code wasn't ever supposed to have more than one value for the enum in the list, but someone commented out the code that ensured that (I gave them a good yelling at).

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fault lies in implementation of the < and > operators, which return incorrect true/false values at times.   They're not needed if CompareTo is implemented as below.

ps. Swap the Type, Year and Period order around if you need to sort in a different order.

```
public int CompareTo(FiscalSamplingPoint point)
{
    if (point == null)
        return 1;

    if (this._periodType != point._periodType)
        return this._periodType < point._periodType? -1 : 1;

    if (this._fiscalYear != point._fiscalYear)
        return this._fiscalYear < point._fiscalYear? -1 : 1;

    if (this._periodNumber != point._periodNumber)
        return this._periodNumber < point._periodNumber? -1 : 1;

    return 0;
}
```

NB I'd also use CompareTo for the `Equals` implementation to avoid duplicating code.  eg.

```
point1.CompareTo(point2) == 0
```